# Why the captcha image is displaying in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my code of captcha.php.I am new to codeigniter so please help me out.
I want to display the captcha image in the browser but the image is not getting displayed over there.
Can anyone tell me where i doing wrong.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Captcha extends CI_Controller{

    public function index(){

        echo "HELLO CAPTCHA <br>";      

        $this->load->helper('captcha');


        $val = array(           
            'word'          => 'Random 123',
            'img_path'      => './Code__Igniter/application/captcha/',
            'img_url'       => 'http://localhost/Code__Igniter/index.php/captcha/',
            'font_path'     => './Code__Igniter/system/fonts/texb.ttf',
            'img_width'     => '300',
            'img_height'   => '50',
            'expiration'    => '3600', 
        );


        $img = create_captcha($val);

        echo $img['time'];
        echo $img['word'];

        $data['imag'] = $img['image'];  

        $this->load->view('header_view');

        $this->load->view('main_view',$data);

    }
}
```

Comment: This is my views through which i am trying to fetch the captcha.<html>
 <head>
 <body>
  MAIN_VIEW BODY PART
   <div id="content">

   
    <?php echo $imag; ?>
 
   
   </div> 
 
 </body>

 </head>

</html>.... Please tell correct me why i am not getting the images over browser

Comment: Did you use an <img> tag to display the image? based on your comment above, it seems like you didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You just Have to

```
<div>
<?php
echo $imag;
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have select wrong image path

```
'img_path'      => './Code__Igniter/application/captcha/',
'img_url'       => 'http://localhost/Code__Igniter/index.php/captcha/',
```

image url is folder path should not contain index.php its only folder path

crea image folder at main folder

like

```
Code__Igniter/captcha
```

now your $val array replace this two value

```
'img_path'      => './captcha/',
'img_url'       => 'http://localhost/Code__Igniter/captcha/',
```